# How can I fade a navbar with a scroll down with React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

is it true that using jQuery with React for animation issues, among others is a bad idea? is it better to use css classes with states?

I have this template with a navbar menu but I would like with the scroll down the bar to perform a jquery fade, which is wrong with my template or how can I add such effect

I have my main template called landing.js

```
import React from 'react';

import NavbarBoots from './Vitae-Plantilla/NavbarBoots';
import NavbarLanding from './Landing-Plantilla/NavbarLanding';
import CabeceraLanding from './Landing-Plantilla/CabeceraLanding';
import CuerpoLanding from './Landing-Plantilla/CuerpoLanding';
import PieLanding from './Landing-Plantilla/PieLanding';

export default class Landing extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if(scrollTop > 100) {
                $('#.main_h').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('#.main_h').fadeIn();
            }

        });
    }
    render() {

        return (
          <div className="container-landing">
                <header id=".main_h"className=".main_h">
                        <NavbarBoots/>
                    <div className="cabecera-landing">
                        <CabeceraLanding title="Cabecera" subtitle="el pais del nunca jamás."/>
                    </div>
                </header> 
                    <div className="body-landing-">
                        <div className="cuerpo-landing">
                            <CuerpoLanding title="Acerca de mi."/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="pie-landing">
                            <PieLanding title="pie"/>
                        </div>

                    </div>
          </div>
        ); 
    }; // render
} // Landing
```

these are the styles of my page but how can I make the navbar go down too.

```
.container-landing {
  .main_h {
    background: url(http://www.vqronline.org/sites/vqr.virginia.edu/files/story-images/petrusich_honis_opener_cssp_aur-mw_oct2015_1.jpg) center no-repeat;

      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      max-height: 70px;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 17px;
      background: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      opacity: 0;
      top: -100px;
      padding-bottom: 6px;
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    }
    .main_h .sticky{
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
      opacity: 1;
      top: 0px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
      .main_h {
        padding-top: 25px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: In general I would say using css animations where possible is preferred over the jQuery, or any javascript, derived animation methods.  The reason being that animations implemented by css itself can potentially benefit from the browser optimizing the operation with the gpu.  Typically animations done with javascript are going to involve frequent changes to the DOM which will result in frequent page redraws and such, which from a performance standpoint, and potentially fluid flow of your animation, is a bad thing.  This is what I've gathered from my own personal research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a "react-friendly" way of doing this (i.e, without manipulating DOM element with jquery):

```
componentDidMount () {      
   window.onscroll =()=>{
       this.setState({currentScrollHeight: window.scrollY})
  }
}
```

The only problem with this is it will rerender literally every time the scroll height changes, even if by just 1 pixel. If that gets too expensive, you can round the value to the nearest, say 50:

```
componentDidMount () {      
   window.onscroll =()=>{
    const newScrollHeight = Math.ceil(window.scrollY / 50) *50;
    if (this.state.currentScrollHeight != newScrollHeight){
        this.setState({currentScrollHeight: newScrollHeight})
    }
  }
}
```

And then in render, something like:

```
render(){
   const opacity = Math.min(100 / this.state.currentScrollHeight  , 1)

    return <div style={{opacity}} id='element-you-want-to-fade'> </div>
}
```

You can experiment with the values (change 100, maybe give it a starting value) to get it to fade the way you want.

Alternatively, for a pure-css library solution, you may want to look into http://scrollmagic.io/

The problem with what you have, other than mixing jquery with react, is that fadeIn and fadeOut literally completely show/hide an element, so the element will always either be completely shown or hidden (in other words, it won't slow-fade).

Comment: Hi DZack I had a problem declaring the constant opacity tells me that TypeError: this.state is null, how can I fix it

Comment: You should declare you state in the component's constructor:

`constructor(props){
     this.state = {
        opacity: 0
    }
  }`

Comment: Using state to handle scroll css sounds like a bad idea

Comment: I did have a laugh at recommending a javascript library as a "pure CSS" solution.