# Increasing opacity of the header on scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working with React js and I have the page complete, but what I am stuck on is that I cannot get the header to increase it's opacity on scroll down.

I followed the solution of some nice guy on stackOverflow but the result is inverse of what I want, here's his answer to someone: [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719757/how-can-i-fade-a-navbar-with-a-scroll-down-with-react)

So this is what I have done:

```
import React from 'react'

class Header extends React.Component{

        constructor(){      
                super()
                this.state = { opacity: 0 }   
        }

        componentDidMount () {      
                window.onscroll =()=>{
                 const newScrollHeight = Math.ceil(window.scrollY / 50) *50;
                 if (this.state.currentScrollHeight !== newScrollHeight){
                     this.setState({currentScrollHeight: newScrollHeight})
                 }
                 else
                 {
                        this.setState({currentScrollHeight:0})
                 }
               }
             }


        render(){

                const opacity = Math.max(100 / this.state.currentScrollHeight  , 1)

        return(
                <header style={{background:opacity}}>
                        <div id="logo-div">
                                <img id = "logo" src="http://demo.themewinter.com/html/exhibz/images/logos/logo.png" alt = "logo"/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="header-headings">
                                <div id="home">
                                        <h2>HOME <i className="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2>
                                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 1</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 2</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 3</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 4</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 5</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 6</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 7</a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="about">
                                        <h2>ABOUT <i className="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2>
                                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">About Us</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Gallery</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">FAQ</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Pricing Table</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Sponsors</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Venue</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Error Page</a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="speakers">
                                        <h2>SPEAKERS <i className="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2>
                                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Speaker-1</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Speaker-2</a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="schedule">
                                        <h2>SCHEDULE <i className="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2>
                                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Schedule List</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Schedule Tab 1</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Schedule Tab 2</a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="blog">
                                        <h2>BLOG <i className="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2>
                                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Blog</a>
                                                <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Blog Details</a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="contact">
                                        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div id="buy-button">
                                        <button>BUY TICKET</button>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </header>
        )
    }
}

export default Header
```

What I want is that when I scroll down, the transparent header increases its opacity from 0.95 to 1,along with the headerStickyFadeDownEffect, and when scrolled back to top, fade back again to 0.

I am recreating a Bootstrap template using react js

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React from 'react';

class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { opacity: 0, currentScrollHeight: 0 };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.onscroll = () => {
            const newScrollHeight = Math.ceil(window.scrollY / 50) * 50;

            this.setState({ currentScrollHeight: newScrollHeight });
        };
    }

    render() {
        const opacity = Math.min(this.state.currentScrollHeight / 100, 1);

        return (
            <header style={{ background: `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`, display: 'flex' }}>
                <div id="logo-div">
                    <img id="logo" src="http://demo.themewinter.com/html/exhibz/images/logos/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                </div>
                <div id="header-headings">
                    <div id="home">
                        <h2>
                            HOME <i className="fas fa-angle-down" />
                        </h2>
                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 1</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 2</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 3</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 4</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 5</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 6</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home 7</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="about">
                        <h2>
                            ABOUT <i className="fas fa-angle-down" />
                        </h2>
                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">About Us</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Gallery</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">FAQ</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Pricing Table</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Sponsors</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Venue</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Error Page</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="speakers">
                        <h2>
                            SPEAKERS <i className="fas fa-angle-down" />
                        </h2>
                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Speaker-1</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Speaker-2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="schedule">
                        <h2>
                            SCHEDULE <i className="fas fa-angle-down" />
                        </h2>
                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Schedule List</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Schedule Tab 1</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Schedule Tab 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="blog">
                        <h2>
                            BLOG <i className="fas fa-angle-down" />
                        </h2>
                        <div className="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Blog</a>
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/">Blog Details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contact">
                        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="buy-button">
                        <button>BUY TICKET</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

There are few of the changes required in your code

```
this.state = { opacity: 0, currentScrollHeight: 0 }
componentDidMount() {
    window.onscroll = () => {
        const newScrollHeight = Math.ceil(window.scrollY / 50) * 50;

        this.setState({ currentScrollHeight: newScrollHeight });
    };
}
```

Just set the height to current and then calculate the minimum, as the opacity expects a value from 0-1 only

```
const opacity = Math.min(this.state.currentScrollHeight / 100, 1);
```

Since opacity is applied on some color you need to give some color to your header

```
<header style={{ background: `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`, display: 'flex' }}>
```

PS:backtick(`) is used to get dynamic values within a string

EDIT: I have post the snippet aswell the screenshot for letting u know its working when u scroll down.
PS. since i dont have all of your code, whatever u provided in question i fixed that
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry Ayushi but it didn't work! 
I have initially set the opacity to 0 in the stylesheet and then applied the above method but the opacity remains the same on scroll! What now?

Comment: For u have to check other pages to set the height, i believe the header will be sticky and its height would be less , so u need to logically fix it : tip try passing the color to header and set the scroller width and all this in its parent component.